# Bootstrap 3 grid alignment issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

ok, I'm a web design newbie so this will probably be an easy one for you.  I'm trying to recreate this in bootstrap:

http://puu.sh/eKEnl/14aa343da4.png

Here's the path I'm on but it doesn't seem like the right one:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">pricing</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">advertise</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">book hotel</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">sponsor our <br>intl course</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">hold events/<br>meetings</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

One of my challenges is to keep each button the same width and height.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Tony

Comment: Okay, you're on the right track, but why not try to finish it out, see what you can come up with, then ask for help if you can't get the full solution? You've got it started, but half-way is half-way.

Comment: Agree with @Mattd you are on the right way, keep in mind that now you might want to have a fixed weight and height for the buttons, really don't know if they are being created in a dynamic way, you could start testing with bootply and share your results here, one example with line height fixed for the three firsts buttons: http://www.bootply.com/MpEz28S6pE

Comment: This design should be very easy to implement. Just read the documentation on the grid system on the official site for Bootstrap and you should be able to get it.http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Ok, here's what i have so far: http://www.bootply.com/lUTpQBYfrq      I'm running into an issue with the position of the type in the circle but other than that, I seem to be close.  I did notice that the entire container doesn't seem to be centered though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact you're doing it wrong. It's just a coincidence you have it running, but in other scenarios it won't, and you'll have other issues like aligning, etc.

Your problem is that you're nesting col.... inside col.... when you actually need to use .row --> .col-...-x (where x is a number and the sum of all those digits plus any offset you have must be 12).

In short: get rid of your col-md-12 container and use the grid system with those buttons, so your first col, first row should be `<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">` and so on

about your circle button issue, change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-center"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">
    <span>important <br/>dates</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and then add this to your CSS:

```
.btn-circle {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center
}
.btn-circle span {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

Since you're actually doing quite well by yourself, try to do it on your own using the explanation above, although you can check the [full code here](http://www.bootply.com/bZ4fI8YZkL) (but really, try to do it by yourself and only use the Bootply as last resource)

Comment: Thank you so much Devin!  I was able to work it out on my own with your explanation.

Comment: glad to help and to know you did it all by yourself, I knew you could! If the answer was useful, please mark it as correct so other users can benefit from it